# Verify my method was called using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the following class:

```
public class ConsignorViewModel : ViewModel
{
    #region Members
    private Consignor _model;
    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public string SearchTerm
    {
        get { return _model.SearchTerm; }
        set
        {
            if (_model.SearchTerm != value)
            {
                _model.SearchTerm = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SearchTerm");
            }
        }
    }

    ...
    #endregion Properties

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpresssion)
    {
        var propertyName = PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName(propertyExpresssion);
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName, bool validatePropertyName = true)
    {
        if(validatePropertyName) VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I basically want to test if the "RaisePropertyChanged" method was called with the right parameter ("SearchTerm") when setting a value to my SearchTerm property.

I think I have to mock my class therefore. How can I do so using Moq?

Comment: Is this `RaisePropertyChanged` virtual? If you want to use Moq (and I do not know if that is a bad approach), it will need to be `virtual` (or non-`sealed` override). Is it `protected internal` or `public`?

Comment: I have added the code of the RaisePropertyChanged method.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a use case for Moq - you can't mock the class under test.

But you can test the `INotifyPropertyChanged` pattern like this:

```
var vm = new ConsignorViewModel();
var raised = 0;

vm.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => {
  if (e.PropertyName == "SearchTerm")
    ++raised;
  else
    Assert.Fail("Unexpected property name");
}

vm.SearchTerm = "42";
Assert.That(raised, Is.EqualTo(1));
```

Comment: Works well, but isn't there any easier approach? Looks like a lot of code to me as I have a lot of properties.

Comment: You can do the test once, but instead of a counter use a `List<string>` to store the names of the changed properties. Change a bunch of properties and then check the list is equal to what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Moq is not the best tool to use there.

You **can** do it with Moq if you make the `RaisePropertyChanged` method `virtual`:

```
protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName, bool validatePropertyName = true)
    ...
```

Then this will work:

```
var mock = new Mock<ConsignorViewModel>(MockBehavior.Loose /* , constructorArguments */);

// use mock
mock.Object.SearchTerm = "42";

// verify the call
mock.Verify(x => x.RaisePropertyChanged("SearchTerm", true));
```

In order for the arrow `x => x.RaisePropertyChanged("SearchTerm", true)` to compile, the method `RaisePropertyChanged` must be accessible from where your test code is. Since it is a `protected` method, you must make your test code inside some class that (is) or derives from `RaisePropertyChanged`. If that is inconvenient, you may accept to relax the access level of `RaisePropertyChanged`, for example:

```
protected internal virtual void RaisePropertyChanged( ... )
    ...
```

Then the test just has to be in the same assembly (project).

Otherwise, you can use Moq's support for `protected` members, but it is a bit ugly:

```
using Moq.Protected;

...

// verify the call
mock.Protected().Verify("RaisePropertyChanged", Times.Once(), "SearchTerm", true);
// Note that "RaisePropertyChanged" is a string,
// since the name RaisePropertyChanged is not in scope.
```